# Generate sequences of adjecent subsets (from a list of lists)

Tags: java, python, ruby, clojure, seq

I have an matrix (array of arrays) in the form

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[12, 23, 34]
[123, 234]
[1234]
```

And want to produce sequences of this matrix that is following each other and is (converted to a string) in the same length as the array at index 0 (top-most). So i.e. the result of this would be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[12, 3, 4]
[1, 23, 4]
[1, 2, 34]
[12, 34]
[123, 4]
[1, 234]
[1234]
```

The thing I want to achive is to get all parts of a string that can be directly connected to each other and splitted i sub arrays (as shown in the example).

The implementation language is irrelevant but preferably in i.e. Python, java, ruby, C#, clojure, Psudo code, or other language at a fairly high level.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're actually asking.

Comment: Are you basically looking to generate every possible permutation of a series of number split into a list?

Comment: Not every possible permutation. Only the ones that comform to the first row. From the specified input should the presented output be generated.

Comment: Why is `[12, 34]` not included?

Comment: How are the rows other than the first in the original matrix relevant to the question?

Comment: @sawa, "Why is [12, 34] not included?" I belive it is not "continuous sequence" :D. I mean each permutation step is equal by 1 sign. And it grows each time when string is ended :). I can't explain exact task, because I can't fully understand it by myself ). But you can see my solution if it will help

Comment: @fl00r Haha. Yeah, it's difficult to understand the question. I gave it a try, but yours seems to fit more to the original example given.

Comment: [12, 34] Should be included. It's a miss from my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I improved the code from my previous one.*

```
a = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

['', '.'].repeated_permutation(a.length - 1).map{|b| a.zip(b).join.split('.')}
```

will give you:

```
[
  ["1234"],
  ["123", "4"],
  ["12", "34"],
  ["12", "3", "4"],
  ["1", "234"],
  ["1", "23", "4"],
  ["1", "2", "34"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
]
```

Comment: Yes, this is Array Chainsaw Massacre. :)

Comment: @fl00r and @steenslag ruby1.9.2 makes me be/do so.

Comment: This one was amazing! I've implemented a version i clojure that I will be using.

Comment: @isakkarlsson Good to know that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python version (**edited** to be more concise; thanks to FMc's suggestions):

```
def consecutive_slice(arr):
    yield arr
    mx = len(arr) + 1
    for size in xrange(2, mx):
        for i in xrange(mx - size):
            yield(arr[:i] + [''.join(arr[i:i+size])] + arr[i+size:])
```

Usage example:

```
>>> for seq in consecutive_slice(['1', '2', '3', '4']):
...     print(seq)
... 
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['12', '3', '4']
['1', '23', '4']
['1', '2', '34']
['123', '4']
['1', '234']
['1234']
```

Comment: This didn't generate `['12','34']`

Comment: @MattH, I believe it shouldn't

Comment: @MattH: To the best of my understanding, `['12', '34']` is not supposed to be generated. I assume the author wants to start with a sequence (`arr`) and slice it into subsequences, each containing *one* consecutive group of elements, where the size of the consecutive group ranges from 1 to `len(arr)`.

Comment: +1 Three minor suggestions, mainly for readability. (1) At the outset, define a convenience variable: `mx = len(arr) + 1`. (2) Use that variable in your first loop: `xrange(2, mx)`. (3) Your second loop can be replaced with the simpler: `for i in xrange(mx - size)`.

Comment: @FMc: Thanks for the suggestions. I've refactored the code accordingly. I agree, it is easier to read :-)

Comment: @Gregg: Ran your code in the Python console and got back: <generator object consecutive_slice at 0x1004cb1e0>. How do I display it? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @seph: You are not doing it wrong. `consecutive_slice` returns a [generator object](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators). You can display the results by iterating over the generator object or using the built-in `list` function to create a list from the generator, i.e. `list(consecutive_slice(['1', '2', '3', '4']))`. I've edited my answer to include a usage example.

Answer (score 1):

```
def adj(ar)
  result = [ar]
  2.upto ar.size do |j|
    0.upto ar.size-j do |i|
      result << [*ar[0, i], ar[i,j].join.to_i, *ar[i+j..-1]]
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Test

```
a = [*1..5]
adj a
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
#  [12, 3, 4, 5], 
#  [1, 23, 4, 5], 
#  [1, 2, 34, 5], 
#  [1, 2, 3, 45], 
#  [123, 4, 5], 
#  [1, 234, 5], 
#  [1, 2, 345], 
#  [1234, 5], 
#  [1, 2345], 
#  [12345]]
```

**EDIT**

If you want it work with Ruby 1.8.7 (upper is 1.9+)

```
def adj(ar)
  result = [ar]
  2.upto ar.size do |j|
    0.upto ar.size-j do |i|
      result << [ar[0, i], ar[i,j].join.to_i, ar[i+j..-1]].flatten
    end
  end
  result
end

a = (1..5).to_a
adj a
#=> same result
```

Comment: @sawa, I've found more `"Ruby"` solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984489/generate-sequences-of-adjecent-subsets-from-a-list-of-lists/5985379#5985379

Answer (score 1):

Oh, Here is a cool functional (is it?) one-line solution:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
result = [array]
2.upto(a.size){ |s| a.each_cons(s).with_index{ |g, i| result << [*(a-g)[0, i], g.join.to_i, *(a-g)[i..-1]] } }
result
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
#  [12, 3, 4], 
#  [1, 23, 4], 
#  [1, 2, 34], 
#  [123, 4], 
#  [1, 234], 
#  [1234]]
```

Comment: No, no, there should be an inject there somewhere

Answer (score 0):

(Ruby version) I believe that this works in the general case for your matrix. I converted to strings so the sort would work out nicely. **Edited** to include ['12', '34'] in the generated sequence.

```
m = [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['12', '23', '34'], ['123', '234'], ['1234']]
m0 = m.first.join
seq = m.map do |row|
  ( 1..row.size ).map { |e| row.combination( e ).to_a }.flatten( 1 ).map do |a|
    m0.include?( str = a.join ) ? ( m0.delete( str ).chars.to_a + a ).sort : nil
  end.compact.uniq
end.flatten 1
```

Comment: just realized that nor this or my implementation suffice to the speficication (that I missed on present fully). It does not generate [12 34] (in this case)... (sry but removed my previous reply before I saw yours)